# CefSharp WPF File not found only on debug mode "CefSharp.Core.Runtime" Version 89.0.170

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp.WPF, I updated to the last version using NuGet, in the previuos version that I had.  I added a Assembly Resolver like this, because I am using AnyCPU (.Net Framework 4.7.2) [Any cpu Support](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714)  :

```
private static Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.StartsWith("CefSharp"))
        {
            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2)[0] + ".dll";



            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                                                   Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                                                   assemblyName);

            string archSpecificPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                                                   Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                                                   assemblyName);

            MessageBox.Show(path);

            try
            {
                return File.Exists(archSpecificPath)
                       ? Assembly.LoadFile(archSpecificPath)
                       : null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }


        }

        return null;
    }
```

After update to version 89.0.170 I notice that there is a new file "CefSharp.Core.Runtime" that now is  the only runtime dependency [CefSharp release notes](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases). After the update I removed the x86 and x64 folder, and also remove the Resolver code, the project run fine in Release mode but when I try to run in Debug mode I get this error when call `new CefSettings()`:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

> Output windows --> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in CefSharp.Wpf.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in CefSharp.Wpf.dll
> Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

[VS code error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70699.jpg)

I tried to find a similar issue but I can't found it , How I need to manage the 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' file?

For sure I am missing something but I can't find it. Also I am not sure if now will run fine in x86 and x64

Comment: You still need the assembly resolve code and the x86/x64 folders. When upgrading you shouldn't need to make any code changes. The assembly resolve can be slightly simplified see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs#L47

Comment: Previously CefSharp.dll, CefSharp.Core.dll and CefSharp.Wpf.dll were all distributed as x86/x64 variants, they are now all AnyCpu libs with CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll being the only CefSharp dll to be architecture specific. All the unmanaged resources like libcef.dll still exist as x64/x86 variants and the browser won't work without them.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where says that CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll is the only runtime dependency? I need to make that wording clearer.

Comment: Thank you @amaitland with the first example that you send me is working now, as you said I steel need the assembly resolve , also I installed cef.redist.x64 and cef.redist.x86 from NuGet on my project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 if you can point me to which part of the release notes needs clarifying I'll see about improving it.

Comment: I think is very clear , thanks for all your help.